# WP8 longlist selector PullToRefresh and null viewport

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to implement `PullToRefresh` on my `longlistselector`. I've wrote my code with the help of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139648/pull-to-refresh-with-long-list-selector-windows-phone-8)

the problem is that the compression event handler is called whenever I scroll up or down, regardless whether I've reached the top or bottom of list or not.
By doing more search, I've found that my solution lays with `viewportcontrol` which is a child element of `longlistselector`.
I tried getting this viewportcontrol using the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
_viewport = FindVisualChild<ViewportControl>(listbox);
```

and by FindName :

```
_viewport  = this.FindName("ViewportControl") as ViewportControl;
```

but it's always returning null. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by creating a custom longlistselector and overriding the OnApplyTemplate method:

```
public class MyLongListSelector : LongListSelector
    {
        public ViewportControl ViewportControl { get; private set; }
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            ViewportControl = (ViewportControl)GetTemplateChild("ViewportControl");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone.